# Golang: Combine two numbers

Tags: go, integer, int64, int32

I feel quite stupid asking this but how can I archive the following in GO?

Let's say I have two int32 which both have the value 33.
How can I combine them into one int32 with the value 3333 instead of 66?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var a, b int32 = 33, 33
a = a*100 + b
fmt.Println(a)
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/fChV2nWxJx).

**Edit:** Here is a version which computes the padding depending on the number:

```
func main() {
    var a, b int32 = 1234, 456
    a = a*padding(b) + b
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func padding(n int32) int32 {
    var p int32 = 1
    for p < n {
        p *= 10
    }
    return p
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JVJuTsxXR-).

Note that you should also check that int32 won't overflow. If you don't want to worry about overflows, you can use a [big.Int](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) instead.

Comment: Yeah but what if the values are different, let's say 1223 and 5644 ?

Comment: In *padding* p must be initialized with 10 to be also correct for b in { 0, 1 }

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea about the performance, compared to Ainar-G's solution, but what about this:

```
var a, b int32 = 33, 33
result, err := strconv.Atoi(fmt.Sprintf("%d%d", a, b))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}        
fmt.Println(int32(result))
```